# Templates :Name resolution:Dependent template arguments : -->can any one tell some more examples for this statement?

Tags: c++, templates

This is the statement from ISO C++ Standard 14.6.2.4:
Dependent template arguments :

> 1. A type template-argument is dependent if the type it specifies 
>         is dependent.
> 2. An integral non-type template-argument is dependent if the constant 
>          expression it specifies is value dependent.
> 3. A non-integral non-type template-argument is dependent if its type
>           is dependent or it has either of the following forms and contains a
>           nested-name-specifier which specifies a class-name that names a 
>           dependent type.
> 4. A template template-argument is dependent if it names a template
>           parameter or is a qualified-id with a nested-name-specifier which 
>           contains a class-name that names a dependent type.

I am unable to understand these points?

Can any one give examples for these statements?

Comment: (FYI: It becomes §14.7.2.4 in C++0x.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understand. I have marked the individual code snippets in the code inline marked according to the line numbers in the OP.

```
struct A{
    void f(){}
};

template<class T> struct B{};

// The template argument B<T> is TYPE depdent on the template parameter T                      (1)
template<class T, class U = B<T> > struct T1{};

// The template argument c is VALUE dependent on the template non type parameter 'c'        (2)
template<class T, char c, int d = c> struct T2{};

// The 2nd template argument is TYPE depdent on the template parameter T                    (3)
template<class T, void (T::*p)(void) = &T::f> struct T3{};

// The template template argument B is TYPE depdent on the template parameter T             (4)
template<class T, template<class U = T> class V = B> struct T4{};


int main(){
    T1<int> t1;
    T2<int, 'A', 2> t2;
    T3<A> t3;
    T4<A> t4; 
}
```

Comment: @Chubsdad: Is This same statement is true under Inheritance..that is by using inheritance..it is true or not.if yes ? can u explain that with an example..Thanks for ur answer

Comment: @Chubsdad : I think you have missed the difference between a `parameter` and an `argument`. `...template argument U is TYPE depdent on the...`, `U` is a template `parameter` not a template `argument`.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav :Can u explain it Programmaticaaly.

Comment: @BE Student : Explain what? The difference between a parameter and an argument?

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav:What you are asking me to tell that difference?

Comment: @BE Student : I am not asking you to tell the difference. I am asking you to make your `Can u explain it Programmaticaaly` statement more clear and precise.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav:Ok .Actually I understtod first 2 points.Later 3,4 IAm unable prove that in terms of a program .Thats i  asked for help.

Comment: @BE Student : As far your opening question is concerned I am not sure about `3rd` and `4th` point{thats why haven't answered to your question yet}. You wait for @Johannes Schaub aur some other guy's answer. They will clarify these points. :)

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav:That is what Iam waiting for u and all..Thanks For u Answers and replies

Comment: @Chubsdad : Looks fine to me now.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: this thread requires your blessing :)